# rich:datascroller number of pages based on the total of records, not on the number of rows from the datatable

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2

I don't know if i'm right, but as far as i know, the number of pages shown on a rich:datascroller, is based on the size of the list populating the datatable.

But here's the thing: let's say that in total, there's 20 records to be shown. I just want to query 10 of them, and make it so there's two pages on the datascroller. I can't query all my records, because there can be times that is something over 300.000 records. I can't leave it in the memory. Is there anyway that this can be achieved?

Here's my code so far:

```
<rich:datascroller for="grdPemissoes" maxPages="5"
    reRender="contentResultadoTable, labelResultados"
    page="#{actionDivisao.pageIndex}"
    pageVar="#{actionDivisao.totalPages}"
    eventsQueue="queueScroller"
</rich:datascroller>
<rich:dataTable id="grdPemissoes" rowClasses=" ,td_cinza"
    value="#{actionDivisao.listaResultados}"
    styleClass="table table-search-result"
    var="divisao" rowKeyVar="row"
    rows="#{actionDivisao.registrosPorPagina}">
                        //columns
</rich:dataTable>
```

Since there's always 10 records, there's no pages to be shown. 
I'm using richfaces 3 and jsf 1.2.

Comment: You can take those 20 records and put them into `#{actionDivisao.listaResultados}`

Comment: That's the same as querying all the results and puting them in the memory. I just want to query the first 10 results and let the datascroller think that there's more than 10 records, so the pages would show up

Comment: When data model is used for data table, then number of pages = listSize / recordPerPage. But in that case you don't need to store all list in memory. You can fetch records related to current page. Or you can always fetch twice this size and display it on two pages.

Answer (score 1):

Tables use a dataModel (`javax.faces.model.DataModel` or a class extending it), if you want to change the default behavior, e.g. return a size different from how many records you have loaded, you will need to implement your own dataModel and pass it to the value attribute of the table:

```
public class MyDataModel extends org.ajax4jsf.model.ExtendedDataModel {

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return this.list.size() + 10; // or something
    }

    …
}
```

You can check an example in the [showcase](http://showcase-rf3.richfaces.org/richfaces/dataTable.jsf?tab=dataModel).